# How to print on an HP printer using a USB from an iPhone

Tags: ios, printing

I need to print from my iPhone and iPad directly to the HP Officejet Pro 9015 printer *without* using Apple Airprint. The printer is connected to the Windows 10 PC by USB. HP Smart is set on the iPhone to the local network.

When I direct connect the iPhone to the Windows PC USB hub the HP Smart app on the iPhone could not find the printer. When I connected the iPhone to the front USB port on the printer it still could not find the printer.

Any ideas? Cheers